# Insert a multiply symbol in multiplication of maths

Tags: tables, symbols

```
\documentclass{article}

% My MWE  original version
% I did use mtpro fonts
% how to use slop since I don't have the package 'slop'
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{  l r   r   r} 
  & $0.0735$            \\
   &\times  $294$           \\
  \hline
  &$2940 $              \\
  &$6615$               \\
  & +$ 1470$                \\
  \hline                    
  &$21.6090$                \\
 \hline                 \\
 \end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I dont understand what you are trying to say, you want to write a multiplication or what?

Comment: Sorry . Yes I just need to insert a symbol ( multiply) and its looks great.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: The package is called `xlop`, not `slop`

Answer (score 8):

I believe this is what you want.  Recommend you read the documentation at http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/generic/xlop/xlop-doc.pdf

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\opmul{0.0735}{294}\qquad
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. What a package!

Answer (score 5):

<sup>This is an answer to [revision 1](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/252478/1) or [revision 2](https://tex.stackexchange.com/revisions/252478/2).</sup>

You mean something like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{ } S[table-format=2.4]}
         & 0.0735  \\
  \times & {294}   \\
  \hline
         & 14.70   \\
  +      & 6.615   \\
  +      & 0.2940  \\
  \hline
  =      & 21.6090 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Or

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{>{$}l<{$} @{ } S[table-format=2.4] @{ } l}
         & 0.0735 & $\times$ 294 \\
  \hline
         & 14.70   \\
  +      & 6.615   \\
  +      & 0.2940  \\
  \hline
  =      & 21.6090 \\
  \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]